# What is the definition of semi-simplication of a group representation?

Tags: representation-theory

When learning Galois representations , it often happens to take the semi-simplication of a 2-dim representation, but I can't find the definition. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional representation of $G$. A filtration $0 = V_0 \subset V_1 \subset \cdots \subset V_{\ell} =V$ of $V$ is called a Jordan-Holder series if all the $V_j$ are subrepresentations and each $V_{j}/V_{j-1}$ is simple. The semisimplification of $V$ is $\bigoplus_{j=1}^{\ell} V_j/V_{j-1}$. By the Jordan-Holder theorem (for modules over the group algebra $k[G]$), this is independent of the choice of Jordan-Holder filtation. [Here](https://math.berkeley.edu/~serganov/math252/notes9.pdf) is a quick proof of Jordan-Holder for modules.

For example, let $E$ be the elliptic curve $y^2 = x (x^2-D)$ where $D$ is not a square. Then the Galois representation on the $2$-torsion is $\rho(g) = \left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1 & \sigma(g) \\ 0 & 1 \end{smallmatrix} \right)$ where $\sigma(g)=0$ if $g(\sqrt{D}) = \sqrt{D}$ and $\sigma(g) = 1$ if $g(\sqrt{D}) = - \sqrt{D}$. The semisimplification is the trivial representation.

Comment: Great！It helps me a lot!